# Conexión a SQL Server desde Wordpress

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, wordpress

tengo un cliente al cual le hice su sitio web en wordpress pero el tiene un ERP en Sql Server, entonces el equipo de tecnología me hizo una tabla en SQL Server para conectarme y extraer de ahí la información de dicha tabla.

Pero estoy buscando información de como puedo hacer eso desde WP por que esa información la tengo que insertar como un post nuevo dentro de WP. Si alguien me puede dar una idea se lo agradecería.

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es saber sobre que versión de PHP está corriendo WP y la arquitectura (x64 o x86), luego debes instalar los [Drivers PHP SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) y el [Driver ODBC 17 para SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=56567), copia los dll que correspondan a tu versión de PHP y arquitectura en la carpeta `php/ext` y añade las extensiones en el archivo PHP.ini (en mi caso uso PHP 7.3, pero en general son los nombres de los dll sin el `.dll`).

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts
```

Guarda el archivo PHP.ini, reinicia los servicios y verifica que el driver se haya añadido correctamente con un archivo PHP asi:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

Si todo esta correcto en el apartado PDO aparecerá `sqlsrv`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso tendrias el acceso a SQL Server y el resto sería hacer lo que necesites con los datos que extraigas, ojala te sirva, suerte.